# How to change serialized data into key/value paires efficiently in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, serialization

```
q=search&title=&post-text=&fkey=12e8c18672ab30ae7977a95f872dc77d&author=&i1l=yaF751&tagnames=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a valid query string, try something like the [ParseQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/parseQuery) plugin. [Query String](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) does this too.